# Flutter GlobalKey<FormState>

Tags: flutter, edittext

Cuando ultilizo la app me arroja el mensaje de:
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

porque estoy usando GlobalKey en varias paginas de la app.
¿Cómo lo resuelvo?
Esto ya no permite trabajar los TextEditingController facilmente.

```
class JosKeys {
  static final josKeys0 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final josKeys1 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final josKeys2 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final josKeys3 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final josKeys4 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final josKeys5 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  static final josKeys6 = GlobalKey<FormState>();
}
```

Comment: Solo puedes usar un key para un widget, como dice el error, multiples widgets no pueden usar el mismo globalkey

Comment: si tengo la idea de eso, pero no puedo llevarlo a acabo. me puedes instruir?

Comment: Deberías comentarnos para que específicamente estas usando esa GlobalKey